# JS template literals: not defined

Tags: javascript, template-literals

As I'm writing this function which holds a parameter 'day', I'de like to log the chosen day to the console.
I'm getting the output 'day is not defined' and I cannot figure out why (I'm new to JS).
I believe 'day' is defined because I call the function with an argument.

```js
const getSleepHours = day => {
  if (day === 'monday'){
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'tuesday'){
    return 7;
  } else if (day === 'wednesday'){
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'thursday'){
    return 9;
  } else if (day === 'friday'){
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'saturday'){
    return 9;
  } else if (day === 'sunday'){
    return 9;
  } else {
    return 'Please enter a valid day';
  }
};

console.log('You have slept for: ' + getSleepHours('sunday') + ' hours');
console.log(`${day}`);
```

Comment: "*I believe 'day' is defined*"–Within the function `getSleepHours` yes, but not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

In the function definition syntax, "day" has to be wrapped in paranthesis () as (day). Below is how i would implement it

```
    const getSleepHours = (day) => { 
        var hours = 0;
        
        switch(day){
           case "sunday":
             hours=1;
           break;
           case "monday":
             hours=2;
           break;
           default:
             hours=0;
        }
    
        return hours;
    }

const daysCount = getSleepHours('sunday');
console.log('You have slept for: '+ getSleepHours("sunday") +' hours');
console.log(daysCount);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const getSleepHours = day => { // this day variable will be considered as argument
  if (day === 'monday'){
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'tuesday'){
    return 7;
  } else if (day === 'wednesday'){
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'thursday'){
    return 9;
  } else if (day === 'friday'){
    return 8;
  } else if (day === 'saturday'){
    return 9;
  } else if (day === 'sunday'){
    return 9;
  } else {
    return 'Please enter a valid day';
  }
};

const day = getSleepHours('sunday'); // define day variable so value will be stored which is returned from function.
console.log('You have slept for: ' + getSleepHours('sunday') + ' hours');
console.log(`${day}`);
```